Is there any legal ambiguity about Anwar al-Awlaki's citizenship?
American media sources seem to generally refer to Anwar al-Awlaki as “U.S.-born” (PBS; NBC; CNN) rather than as a “U.S. citizen.”
I'm just curious whether legally there is any ambiguity in al-Awlaki's citizenship status (at the time of his death), or if the media is just avoiding stating that directly. I can't find anything to suggest that his citizenship was revoked through some legal process, or that he renounced it. (Perhaps certain actions can get your citizenship revoked automatically?)

This BBC report states he was a US citizen:

US and Yemeni officials later named one of those as Samir Khan, also a US citizen but of Pakistani origin, who produced an online magazine promoting al-Qaeda's ideology.

Same with this NBC article:

The 38-year-old al-Awlaki, a U.S. citizen born in New Mexico to Yemeni parents, preached at a Virginia mosque that Hasan's family attended.

